# Write a program that accepts user input from the user till 0 is entered

Tags: javascript

> Write a program that accepts user input from the user till 0 is entered. Then prints the total number of entries, the addition of their values, and an average of their values as well as the minimum and the maximum number entered. If a negative number is entered it should be converted into a positive and to be added to the sum.

Enter value 22.5
Enter value 14.5
Enter value 7.2
Enter value 33.1
Enter value 0.0

Total entries: 4
Sum: 77.3
Average: 19.325
Minimum: 7.2
Maximum: 33.1

I have this exercise to do and I need help with it.

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour], look around, and read the [help], esp. *[ask]*. Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and **give it a try**. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it, [search](/help/searching) [thoroughly](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site:stackoverflow.com), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help. [More here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/).

Answer (score 0):

General idea

```js
function fn(number, arr = []) {
  if (number === 0) {
    return arr // Calculate by arr
  } else {
    arr.push(Math.abs(number))
    return (number) => fn(number, arr)
  }
}
console.log(fn(1)(2)(3)(5)(0)); // [1, 2, 3, 5]
```